# Prove that $\zeta (4)\le 1.1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Prove the following inequality

$$\zeta (4)\le 1.1$$

I saw on the site some proofs for $\zeta(4)$ that use Fourier or Euler's way for computing its precise value, and that's fine and I can use it. Still, I wonder if there is a simpler  way around for proving
this inequality.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\zeta(4) < \sum_{n=1}^{6} \frac{1}{n^{4}} + \int_{6}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^4} < 1.1$$

Comment: nice! Thanks! (+1)

Comment: (a) I suspect it should be $\int_{6}^{\infty}$ rather than $\int_{7}^{\infty}$ to justify the first $\lt$

Comment: (b) $$\zeta(4) < \sum_{n=1}^{3} \frac{1}{n^{4}} + \int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^4} < 1.0872$$ seems to work

Comment: @ Henry: I just checked that and you're perfectly right! (+1) Thank you. The second version looks better.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\zeta(4)&<&\sum_{n=1}^{9}\frac{1}{n^4} +\left(\sum_{n=10}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^2 \\
&=& \sum_{n=1}^{9}\frac{1}{n^4} + \left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\sum_{n=1}^{9}\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^2 \\
&=& 1.0929965...
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: it seems a bit harder :-) (+1)

Answer (score 4):

One has
$${1\over (n-{1\over2})^3}-{1\over (n+{1\over2})^3}={3n^2+{1\over4}\over (n^2-{1\over4})^3}>{3\over n^4}\ .$$
Therefore one obtains the telescopic sum
$$\eqalign{\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^4}&=1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty{1\over n^4}< 1+{1\over3}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\Bigl({1\over (n-{1\over2})^3}-{1\over (n+{1\over2})^3}\Bigr)\cr &=1+{1\over3}{1\over(2-{1\over2})^3}=1+{8\over81}<1.1\ .\cr}$$

Comment: thank you for your solution.